# nmb: unrecognized service when installing Samba

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I've followed [these steps](http://charlesa.net/tutorials/centos/centossamba.php) to install Samba on my CentOS package. However, when I try to run `chkconfig --level 345 nmb on`, I get a `nmb: unrecognized service` error.

I tried `service nmb status` and `service nmb restart` with the same error message returning.

There doesn't seem to be anything regarding this, what's wrong? Why do I not have nmb installed, and how can I get it installed?

Comment: Did the yum install samba complete correctly ?

Comment: @Iain I unistalled Samba and now re-installed. Same error, no nmb, and it looks like Samba installed correctly. Here's the full text of the install: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M08SJSZ4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a CentOS 5.8 system I have (like the one you are using), it appears that the `smb` and `nmb` services are managed together through the `/etc/init.d/smb` file

```
service smb start
Starting SMB services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NMB services:                                     [  OK  ]
```

Whereas on a CentOS 6.3 system they are managed as separate services. So your

```
chkconfig --level 345 smb
```

will also have configured nmb.

I don't know why the page you reference says to use the separate services. The [RHEL 5 deployment guide(21.2.1)](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-samba-daemons.html#s2-samba-services) says nmb is controlled by smb whereas the the [RHEL 6 deployment guide (17.1.2.1)](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-File_and_Print_Servers.html#samba-rgs-overview) says they are separate services.